# Oracle: query or procedure to traverse table

Tags: recursion, stored-procedures, oracle12c, traversal

I have a table made in this way:

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35108337 | B0110555 |  |
| 35108337 | E15627104 |  |
| 35108338 | E15627104 |  |
| 800384 | L0309599 | 18181 |
| 800384 | E1359191 |  |
| 800385 | B0110556 |  |
| 800385 | E1359191 |  |
| 1030137 | L0309597 | 18181 |
| 1030137 | E1458050 |  |
| 1030138 | B0110556 |  |
| 1030138 | E1458050 |  |
| 2042225 | B0110555 |  |
| 2042225 | E1896214 |  |
| 2042227 | B0110555 |  |
| 2042227 | E1896215 |  |
| 2055249 | B0110555 |  |
| 2055249 | E292177 |  |
| 2055250 | B0110556 |  |
| 2055250 | E1900966 |  |
| 2055251 | E1900966 |  |
| 2055251 | E292177 |  |
| 25908098 | E1896215 |  |
| 25908099 | E1896214 |  |

and I need to navigate it through column_a and column_b. I know the starting point, which is COLUMN_A with value '35108338'. Once I got starting point, I need to check value of COLUMN_B, look for this value in COLUMN_B and take COLUMN_A, look value and look for it in COLUMN_A (which not already taken), until I will reach a record with COLUMN_C not NULL.
For example, staring from '35108338', I will have:

1. COLUMN_A: 35108338 COLUMN_B: E15627104
2. COLUMN_A: 35108337 COLUMN_B: E15627104
3. COLUMN_A: 35108337 COLUMN_B: B0110555
4. COLUMN_A: 2055249  COLUMN_B: B0110555
5. COLUMN_A: 2055249  COLUMN_B: E292177
6. COLUMN_A: 2055251  COLUMN_B: E292177
7. COLUMN_A: 2055251  COLUMN_B: E1900966
8. COLUMN_A: 2055250  COLUMN_B: E1900966
9. COLUMN_A: 2055250  COLUMN_B: B0110556
10. COLUMN_A: 1030138 COLUMN_B: B0110556
11. COLUMN_A: 1030138 COLUMN_B: E1458050
12. COLUMN_A: 1030137 COLUMN_B: E1458050
13. COLUMN_A: 1030137 COLUMN_B: L0309597

I may never reach a record with a column_c not null
I may have multiple roads to do. For example B0110555 is repeating 4 times, so there's more than one road.

I tried with a stored procedure, to make a bulk collect of these data and to manage it with arrays, but I have problem when multiple roads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query and alternate matching on `column_a` and `column_b`:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       LEVEL,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(
         CASE MOD(LEVEL, 2)
         WHEN 1
         THEN TO_CHAR(column_a)
         ELSE column_b
         END,
         '->'
       ) AS path
FROM   table_name t
START WITH column_a = 35108338
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
           (MOD(LEVEL, 2) = 0 AND PRIOR column_b = column_b)
OR         (MOD(LEVEL, 2) = 1 AND PRIOR column_a = column_a)
ORDER SIBLINGS BY column_a, column_b
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C) AS
SELECT 35108337, 'B0110555',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 35108337, 'E15627104', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 35108338, 'E15627104', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 800384,   'L0309599', 18181 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 800384,   'E1359191', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 800385,   'B0110556', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 800385,   'E1359191', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1030137,  'L0309597', 18181 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1030137,  'E1458050', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1030138,  'B0110556', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1030138,  'E1458050', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2042225,  'B0110555', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2042225,  'E1896214', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2042227,  'B0110555', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2042227,  'E1896215', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2055249,  'B0110555', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2055249,  'E292177',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2055250,  'B0110556', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2055250,  'E1900966', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2055251,  'E1900966', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2055251,  'E292177',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 25908098, 'E1896215', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 25908099, 'E1896214', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C | LEVEL | PATH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35108338 | E15627104 | *null* | 1 | ->35108338 |
| 35108337 | E15627104 | *null* | 2 | ->35108338->E15627104 |
| 35108337 | B0110555 | *null* | 3 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337 |
| 2042225 | B0110555 | *null* | 4 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555 |
| 2042225 | E1896214 | *null* | 5 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2042225 |
| 25908099 | E1896214 | *null* | 6 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2042225->E1896214 |
| 2042227 | B0110555 | *null* | 4 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555 |
| 2042227 | E1896215 | *null* | 5 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2042227 |
| 25908098 | E1896215 | *null* | 6 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2042227->E1896215 |
| 2055249 | B0110555 | *null* | 4 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555 |
| 2055249 | E292177 | *null* | 5 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249 |
| 2055251 | E292177 | *null* | 6 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177 |
| 2055251 | E1900966 | *null* | 7 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251 |
| 2055250 | E1900966 | *null* | 8 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966 |
| 2055250 | B0110556 | *null* | 9 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250 |
| 800385 | B0110556 | *null* | 10 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556 |
| 800385 | E1359191 | *null* | 11 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556->800385 |
| 800384 | E1359191 | *null* | 12 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556->800385->E1359191 |
| 800384 | L0309599 | 18181 | 13 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556->800385->E1359191->800384 |
| 1030138 | B0110556 | *null* | 10 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556 |
| 1030138 | E1458050 | *null* | 11 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556->1030138 |
| 1030137 | E1458050 | *null* | 12 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556->1030138->E1458050 |
| 1030137 | L0309597 | 18181 | 13 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556->1030138->E1458050->1030137 |

If you just want to find the non-null `column_c` values then add a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
...
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  column_c IS NOT NULL
START WITH column_a = 35108338
...
```

Which outputs:

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C | LEVEL | PATH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 800384 | L0309599 | 18181 | 13 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556->800385->E1359191->800384 |
| 1030137 | L0309597 | 18181 | 13 | ->35108338->E15627104->35108337->B0110555->2055249->E292177->2055251->E1900966->2055250->B0110556->1030138->E1458050->1030137 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ahRLe2S8)